# How to close connection with Rabbit MQ broker using spring-amqp

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

We have been struggling with this for sometime now. Below is our configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

<context:property-placeholder location="../spring.properties" />

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="${app.mq.host}" username="${app.mq.username}" 
                           password="${app.mq.password}" virtual-host="${app.mq.virtualhost}" port="${app.mq.port}"/> 

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactorySettlement" host="${app.mq.host}" username="${app.mq.username}" 
                           password="${app.mq.password}" virtual-host="${app.mq.settlementVirtualHost}" port="${app.mq.port}"/>

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactoryAuth" host="${app.mq.host}" username="${app.mq.username}" 
                           password="${app.mq.password}" virtual-host="${app.mq.oAuthVirtualHost}" port="${app.mq.port}" />

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactoryVault" host="${app.mq.host}" username="${app.mq.username}" 
                           password="${app.mq.password}" virtual-host="${app.mq.vaultVirtualHost}" port="${app.mq.port}" />

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactoryWebservice" host="${app.mq.host}" username="${app.mq.username}" 
                           password="${app.mq.password}" virtual-host="${app.mq.webserviceVirtualHost}" port="${app.mq.port}" /> 

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactoryCMS" host="${app.mq.host}" username="${app.mq.username}"
                           password="${app.mq.password}" virtual-host="${app.mq.cmsVirtualHost}" port="${app.mq.port}" />

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactoryTreasury" host="${app.mq.host}" username="${app.mq.username}"
                           password="${app.mq.password}" virtual-host="${app.mq.treasuryVirtualHost}" port="${app.mq.port}" />

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactoryBankVault" host="${app.mq.host}" username="${app.mq.username}"
                           password="${app.mq.password}" virtual-host="${app.mq.bankVaultVirtualHost}" port="${app.mq.port}" />

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactoryAnalyticsData" host="${app.mq.analytics_host}" username="${app.mq.analytics_username}"
                               password="${app.mq.analytics_password}" virtual-host="${app.mq.analyticsdataVirtualHost}" port="${app.mq.port}" />

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactoryChat" host="${app.mq.host}" username="${app.mq.username}"
                               password="${app.mq.password}" virtual-host="${app.mq.chatVirtualHost}" port="${app.mq.port}" />

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactoryFittipaldi" host="${app.mq.fittipaldi_host}" username="${app.mq.fittipaldi_username}"
                            password="${app.mq.fittipaldi_password}" virtual-host="${app.mq.fittipaldiVirtualHost}" port="${app.mq.port}" />

<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" reply-timeout="10" />
<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplateSettlement" connection-factory="connectionFactorySettlement" reply-timeout="10" />
<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplateCMS" connection-factory="connectionFactoryCMS" reply-timeout="10" />
<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplateVault" connection-factory="connectionFactoryVault" reply-timeout="10" />
<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplateTreasury" connection-factory="connectionFactoryTreasury" reply-timeout="10" />
<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplateWebservice" connection-factory="connectionFactoryWebservice" reply-timeout="10" />
<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplateBankVault" connection-factory="connectionFactoryBankVault" reply-timeout="10" />
<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplateAnalyticsData" connection-factory="connectionFactoryAnalyticsData" reply-timeout="10" />
<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplateChat" connection-factory="connectionFactoryChat" reply-timeout="10" />
<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplateAuth" connection-factory="connectionFactoryAuth" reply-timeout="1" />
<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplateFitti" connection-factory="connectionFactoryFittipaldi" reply-timeout="5" />

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

</beans>
```

When we try to access the connection factory from java code and execute the destroy method, the connections do not close. Moreover when we inspect the open connections for that connection factory it shows no open connections but rabbitmq in practice has one open connection.

```
RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = (RabbitTemplate) rabbitTemplateMap.get(String.valueOf(key));
CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = (CachingConnectionFactory) rabbitTemplate.getConnectionFactory();
cachingConnectionFactory.destroy();
```

The above code snippet does not succeed in closing the connections. We are using the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
     <version>1.3.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This requirement arises because of a peculiar situation wherein when the connections get blocked we want to provide for an option to shift to a substitute broker. Hence we have to close the current connections and establish new connections with the substitute broker. Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2):

1.3.9 is quite an old release (the current version is 1.6.1).

However, I am not aware of any problems with closing the connection by using the `destroy()` method. In 1.5 we added `resetConnection()` which has a less scary name but it does the same thing as `destroy()`.

If you have any listener containers, the connection will be immediately be re-established after the reset; similarly, if a message is published with the template the connection will be re-created.

If you still feel there's a problem, I suggest you use a network monitor such as wireshark or tcpdump to see what's going on.

Comment: In addition to Gary's solution, also use jdk 1.7 try with resources (Autocloseable) to release/close connections.

Comment: Hey Gary I tried upgrading to 1.5.2.RELEASE but still no luck with resetConnection(). Still getting 0 openConnections. Can you direct to some source which provides an in-depth detail about the AMQP connection.

Comment: As I said, you need to look at a network monitor - from Spring AMQP's perspective the connection is always closed by `destroy()` and `resetConnection()`. You can also turn on DEBUG or TRACE logging which might give you some clues. If you still can't figure it out; please post a small test app that exhibits the problem.